# Why wont Rtrim clear spaces (for comparison)

Tags: t-sql, trim, content-length

I have a a col that is a text field (i know not used any more) that i need to compare. (the instruction field is a text field)
`Case when rtrim(cast(RT.INSTRUCTIONS as varchar(max))) = rtrim(cast(HQ.INSTRUCTIONS as varchar(max))) then 'TRUE' Else 'FALSE' end as INSTRUCTIONS`.

the value in `RT.Instructions` is "Check the oil levels every 30 hours. "
the value in `HQ.Instructions` is "Check the oil levels every 30 hours."

Why wont the trailing blank go away. i did a `len` on both and `hq` is 1 less then the `rt` value.
I also am having the same issue on a `varchar(60)` field.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: The DB is Tsql 2008

Comment: Are you sure it is a space char(32) and not some other control character?

Comment: I am not seeing any values other then "Blank""Empty" spaces on the end

Comment: replace " " with "" and see if you still have the blank spaces.. if you do it's not a space but some other non-display character... you can figure it out by using ASCII on each character after the period.  could be a tab, hard return etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is a character that isn't being picked up. Maybe the following will be useful in finding that value. Or maybe just get you started down the right path.

```
DECLARE @Char INT = 0
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (Id INT, Chr VARCHAR(5), Instructions VARCHAR(MAX), c VARCHAR(MAX))
WHILE @Char < = 256
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT Id
      ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CHAR(@Char)) Chr
      ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,RIGHT(RTRIM(rt.Instructions),1)) InstructionChar
      ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CHAR(CONVERT(int,@Char))) c
FROM YourTable
WHERE RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) LIKE '%'+CHAR(CONVERT(int,@Char))
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE '[A-Za-z]'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE '.'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE ']'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE ')'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE '"'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE '}'
  AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Instructions),1) NOT LIKE '/'
SET @Char = @Char + 1
END
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM @Tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry : I'm not allowed to write comments yet

First try :

```
Case when left(rtrim(cast(RT.INSTRUCTIONS as varchar(max))),len(HQ.INSTRUCTIONS)) = rtrim(cast(HQ.INSTRUCTIONS as varchar(max))) then 'TRUE' Else 'FALSE' end as INSTRUCTIONS
```

To check if no other issue is concerned.

Then do :

```
SELECT ASCII(right(RT.INSTRUCTIONS,1))
```

To confirm that the trailling space is a "real" space : this query should display 32.

CHAR(32) => ' '

ASCII (' ') => 32

I bet you will get 16O. 160 means the last caracter is an non-breaking space witch is not concerned by trim functions...

If so, you will have to build a scalar function like :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Replace_NonBreakingSpace]
(
    @InputString varchar(max),
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(@InputString, char(160), char(32))
END
```

And then :

```
Case when rtrim(dbo.fn_Replace_NonBreakingSpace(RT.INSTRUCTIONS)) = rtrim(dbo.fn_Replace_NonBreakingSpace(HQ.INSTRUCTIONS)) then 'TRUE' Else 'FALSE' end as INSTRUCTIONS
```